# Extracting plain text from EPUB

Tags: plain-text, epub, data-extraction

I have loads of EPUBS from which I need to extract plain text,
without any formatting or other information.

In order to creat wordlists, I got hold of many publications of a language in EPUB format. So I need to transform these to plain txt files, without any images or other formatting data.

Comment: What OS shall the software run on? Any price limit? For cross-platform solution, take a look at [Calibre](/search?q=calibre+is%3Aa), which can convert between many formats (including epub and txt).

Comment: Sorry, Izzy. I didn;t notice this comment before posting Calibre as an answer. Great minds think alike :-) It really is the best, though

Comment: @Mawg for punishment, I've upvoted your answer. I fully agree :)

Comment: Let's see if the OP agrees (accepts the answer, to help others in future). Btw, are you runing for moderator?

Answer (score 3):

The best known (and IMO most full featured) eBook converter is [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/).

[This page](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#what-formats-does-calibre-support-conversion-to-from) says that

> calibre supports the conversion of many input formats to many output
>   formats. It can convert every input format in the following list, to
>   every output format.
>
> Input Formats: AZW, AZW3, AZW4, CBZ, CBR, CBC, CHM, DJVU, DOCX, **EPUB**,
>   FB2, FBZ, HTML, HTMLZ, LIT, LRF, MOBI, ODT, PDF, PRC, PDB, PML, RB,
>   RTF, SNB, TCR, TXT, TXTZ
>
> Output Formats: AZW3, EPUB, DOCX, FB2, HTMLZ, OEB, LIT, LRF, MOBI,
>   PDB, PMLZ, RB, PDF, RTF, SNB, TCR, TXT, **TXTZ**, ZIP

Calibre is stable (10 years already), free and runs on Windows, Linux & osx.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple answer:

click on the file and change the extension from .epub to .zip.
Extract the Zip-folder...inside you will find many xhtml files.
open all of them with notepad++.

Now search for

```
<.*?>|</.*?>
```

and

replace with : `\r\n` (this for new line)

Through that you removed all the html tags

(keep regular expressions ticked --> follow her/him
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807928/find-replace-regex-to-remove-html-tags)

now use the combine plug-in for notepad++,
combine everything and you have one file with plain text

Comment: If the epub uses "highlighting" (e.g. `<b><i><em>`), the result will be a mess.